# Expected value and standard deviation of greater from two normal distributions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Let's assume I have two normal distributions, X and Y with known expected values and standard deviations. How to calculate the distribution of greater values from random pairs of values from these distributions?
If it's not clear, step by step looks like that:

Based on E(X) and D(X) I sample one result, got 10.
Based on E(Y) and D(Y) I sample one result, got 15.
15 is greater than 10, so we put 15 in our result set Z. If we'd receive 10 from X and 8 from Y, we put 10 in result set Z.

What are the parameters E(Z) and D(Z) (and is it still a normal distribution)?

Comment: Is the pair $(X,Y)$ Gaussian? or even are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @LetacGérard X and Y are independent. 
The idea behind this task came from the statistics I have read that married person earns on average 55% more than single. Doing A LOT of assumptions (salaries are normal distributions and are independent) I want to check how much of this value can be explained by decision that for a random pair(couple) only higher-earner goes to work. Of course, scientifically, the assumptions are wrong, but that's always some clue how this type of decision can affect this :)

I have made a simulation in Python for this, but a formula is going to be much more useful.

Comment: I assume the two variables are independent. The CDF (cumulative distribution function) of the maximum of the two is the product of the CDFs of the underlying variables, since the max is smaller than a given value iff all variables are smaller than that given value. If you want the density function, just differentiate the product. The CDF of a normal variable is the erf function.

Comment: EDIT : you have to translate and scale the erf function to get the CDF of your variables. CDF can be used to compute the average by doing an integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=a+Z_1$ and $Y=b+Z_2$ where $Z_1$ and  $Z_2$ are $N(0,1)$ and independent, then $$M=\max(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y+|X-Y|)$$ is certainly not Gaussian since the density of $M$ is $\Phi(m-b)\phi(m-a)+\Phi(m-b)\phi(m-b)$ where $\phi$ is the density of $N(0,1)$ and $\Phi(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\phi(x)dx.$ The expectation of $M$ is given by the following formula, since the density of $Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(Z_1-Z_2)$ is $\phi$ :
$$E(M)=\frac{a+b}{2}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|a-b+\sqrt{2}z|\phi(z)dz.$$ This  is computable only by numerical analysis if $a\neq b.$

I have not computed $E(M^2)$ but if $a$ and $b$ are large enough an approximation of $M^2$ is
$$\max(X^2,Y^2)=\frac{1}{2}(X^2+Y^2+|X^2-Y^2|).$$ But I am afraid that both $E(M^2)$ and $E(\max(X^2,Y^2))$ end up with a double integral.